# Noun + V-ing without V-to-be OR relative pronoun

Tags: ielts

I've read [this](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/120034/how-can-i-omit-which-that-who-and-passive-voice-in-sentences), and the answer states we can omit **relative clause heads** when the verb that follows them is a **present participle**

Can we really say:

**"The baby sleeping is Mike's son"**

instead of saying:

**"The baby who is sleeping is Mike's son."**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's more common to say "the sleeping baby". I would use the second one if you add more modifiers: e.g. "The baby sleeping in the couch is Mike's son".

Comment: @hbtpoprock The practice here is [to wait for at least 24 hours before accepting an answer](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1307/not-so-fast-when-should-i-accept-my-answer). My answer could be wrong.

Comment: So we need something to separate them for those (which are) similar to this case? Is this omission correct? @user178049

Comment: The omission is correct but I think it's more common to say "the sleeping baby". They actually mean the same think.

Comment: One last thing, ". . . separate them for those **(which are)** similar to this case? . . ." Is it correct to omit **(which are)** here?

Comment: Yes. It's correct.

Comment: Ty very much, l'll wait for the next 24 hr :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85556/discussion-between-hbtpoprock-and-user178049).